# QScintilla highlight match words

Tags: qt, qscintilla

Im trying to highlight all the match words on the editor and can't seem to figure out how to properly highlight the text.  I can successfully loop through all the found matches but cant seem to find the right call to highlight it.  Here is my code:

```
bool found = true;  

while(found)
{
    editor->getCursorPosition(&line, &index);

    qDebug() << "line: " << line << " index: " << index;

    found = editor->findFirst(pattern, use_regular_expression, is_case_sensitive, match_whole_word_only, use_wrap, search_forward);

    if(found)
    {
        int start = editor->positionFromLineIndex(line, index);
        int end = editor->positionFromLineIndex(line, index + pattern.length());

        qDebug() << "line: " << line << " start: " << start << " end: " << end;

        // Attempts to highlight
        editor->SendScintilla(QsciScintilla::SCI_INDICGETSTYLE, QsciScintilla::INDIC_BOX);
        editor->SendScintilla(QsciScintilla::SCI_INDICSETFORE, 0x007f00);
        //child[0]->SendScintilla(QsciScintilla::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE, start, end - start);
        editor->SendScintilla(QsciScintilla::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE, start, end - start);
        editor->setIndicatorForegroundColor(QColor(159, 144, 0));
      //  editor->setColor(QColor(159, 144, 0));**
    }
}
```

my qDebug()'s is showing that its going through each line and finding the matches and the position of the occurance of the word.  But code under the comment **// Attempts to highlight** is where I cant seem to figure out.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICSETSTYLE,0, INDIC_BOX);

QString docText = text();
int end = docText.lastIndexOf(findText);
int cur = -1; 

if(end != -1) {

   while(cur != end) {
        cur = docText.indexOf(findText,cur+1);`
        SendScintilla(QsciScintillaBase::SCI_INDICATORFILLRANGE,cur,
            findText.length());
   }
}
```